# Can I pull in the Data Categories for an Article into a custom field that would allow me to sort by Data Category in a list view?

Tags: lightning, custom-field, knowledge

I know there can be multiple data categories, but if I could pull them into a custom field, I could at least do a “contains” filter for the articles.

What formula in a custom field on the Knowledge object would pull in the data categories?

Comment: Check my answer, it will going to work for you

Answer (score 3):

Try using [KnowledgeArticleVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticleversion.htm) instead of KnowledgeArticle. From the Object Reference:

> Use this object to:
>
> - Query or search generically across multiple article types.
> - Filter on a specific version.
> - Update standard fields, those fields that are updateable, in draft versions.
>
> When you query on the archived article, the results include both the article and the article’s archived versions.

Also, use `KnowledgeArticleVersion` with `describeDataCategoryGroups()` and `describeDataCategoryGroupStructures()` to return the category groups and the category structure associated with Salesforce Knowledge.

You can filter by `PublishStatus='online'` to get only the current version available.

Comment: it is tricky as trigger is not supported, check my answer

Answer (score 2):

> First of all, formula field will not going to work in this scenario.

Knowledge Article Version can have multiple DataCategories.Refer this data model. [Salesforce Knowledge Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_erd_knowledge.htm)

[image: DM]

> Secondly, trigger is not supported on Article Types.

**Solution**

- Create a Custom Field `Data_Categories__c` Text (255) in the Article Type (e.g. Help Document is Article Type)
- Create an `@invocable` method like this which will retrieve data categories based on the Article Type Version and finally update those in the Custom field:

Code

```
public class ArticleAction {
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void updateArticleTypeForDataCategories(List<Id> articleTypeIds) 
    {
        List<Help_Document__kav> lstArticleType = [SELECT Id, Title, Data_Categories__c FROM Help_Document__kav WHERE Id IN:articleTypeIds 
                                                    AND PublishStatus = 'draft'];

        List<Help_Document__DataCategorySelection> lstDC = [SELECT ParentId, DataCategoryName   FROM Help_Document__DataCategorySelection
                                                            WHERE ParentId IN:articleTypeIds];

        Map<Id, String> datacategoryNameMap = new Map<Id, String>();

        for(Help_Document__DataCategorySelection dcObj:lstDC)
        {   
            if(datacategoryNameMap.containsKey(dcObj.ParentId))
            {
                String str =  datacategoryNameMap.get(dcObj.ParentId);
                datacategoryNameMap.put(dcObj.ParentId, str + ',' + dcObj.DataCategoryName);
            }
            else
            {
                datacategoryNameMap.put(dcObj.ParentId, dcObj.DataCategoryName);
            }
        }

        for(Help_Document__kav artObj:lstArticleType)
        {
            if(datacategoryNameMap.containsKey(artObj.Id))
            {
                artObj.Data_Categories__c = datacategoryNameMap.get(artObj.Id);
            }
        }

        update lstArticleType;
    }    
}
```

- Call this invocable method from Process builder. You will see dataCategories will be saved in Comma delimited way.

[image: Invocable from PB]

- For Archived articles, make those as `draft` and finally call this method from DeveloperConsole or other batch process.

Comment: is that my answer worked for u? did u check that?