# How to trigger a Process Builder when a DataCategorySelection is created for a Knowledge Article

Tags: apex, lightning-knowledge

I am trying to create a Process Builder that copies the Data Category into a custom field on the Lightning Knowledge Article.
[image]

I have figured the Apex code to do that, thanks to this post [Can I pull in the Data Categories for an Article into a custom field that would allow me to sort by Data Category in a list view?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/184464/can-i-pull-in-the-data-categories-for-an-article-into-a-custom-field-that-would)

But, I am unable to think of a way to trigger this process builder whenever the Data Category is set/changed. How do I detect a change on the DataCategorySelection?

Comment: The object is probably not available for Process Builder.  Have you tried Flow instead?

Comment: you are right, looks like Apex is the only way we can access the DataCategorySelections object. I have tried to create a before update trigger to populate the Data Category but, triggers dont activate when an article is published.